# how to group drop downs based on attributes names in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, laravel-5

One product has multiple attributes, each combination represent an individual product. As you add variable products with variations in woocommerce (WordPress).

Now I've product attributes in array and confused how can I create multiple drop downs based on multiple categories.

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 13
    "name" => "size"
    "value" => "small"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 14
    "name" => "size"
    "value" => "large"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 19
    "name" => "color"
    "value" => "white"
  ]
]
```

As index 0, 1 has same name "Size" having different values, so it should display in a one dropdown and other one should display on another drop down.

I know my logic is wrong here to print out drop downs can you guys help me ?

```
<select class="form-control" id="attribute" name="attribute[]" style="width:70%;">
@foreach($attributes as $attribute)
<option value="">Select {{  $attribute->name }}</option>
<option value="{{ $attribute->id }}">{{ $attribute->value }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Am I right in saying you want them grouped by the name?

Comment: Yes you can say that

Comment: You should add a Type in your attributes table. So you can have dropdowns for each type. (Sizes/colors/..) Types can also be its seperate table. If you also want to add types

Comment: Can't we differentiate them based on the 'names' each attribute has?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections) to group the attributes by their type and then loop through them that way:

```
@foreach(collect($attributes)->groupBy('type') as $options)

    <label>{{ $options->first()->name }}</label>

    <select class="form-control">
        @foreach($options as $option)
            <option value="{{ $option->id }}">{{ $option->value }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
@endforeach
```

You will need to sort the `name` attribute for the selects.

Comment: I think it's `->groupBy('name')` instead of `->groupBy('type')` but it seems like the simplest working solution.